# Files written with fs.writeFile have extra new lines compared to console.log. Why?

Tags: node.js, windows, newline, writefile

I have the following code:

```
async function writeFile(path: string, content: string): Promise<void> {
  console.log(content);
  try {
    await fs.writeFile(path, content, "utf8");
  } catch (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
}
```

console.log prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?tgml 2.0?>

<Tgml Height="10" Stretch="Uniform" Width="10">
  <Layer Stroke="None" Fill="#000000" Name="viewbox-clip">
    <Translate X="5" Y="5"/>
    <Rectangle Height="10" Left="0" Top="0" Width="10"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="#FFFFFF" Height="8" Left="1" Top="1" Width="8"/>
  </Layer>
</Tgml>
```

Opening the written file (in Sublime Text or Notepad at least) shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?tgml 2.0?>



<Tgml Height="10" Stretch="Uniform" Width="10">

  <Layer Stroke="None" Fill="#000000" Name="viewbox-clip">

    <Translate X="5" Y="5"/>

    <Rectangle Height="10" Left="0" Top="0" Width="10"/>

    <Ellipse Fill="#FFFFFF" Height="8" Left="1" Top="1" Width="8"/>

  </Layer>

</Tgml>
```

- Why are there extra line endings in the written file compared to console log?
- How can I make the written file look like the output in console.log, in other words how can I opt to not add extra new lines?

Here is information about my environment in case it is relevant to the issue: Windows, console logs to PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation might be that your data contains `\r\r\n` line breaks for whatever reason and that your terminal interprets and prints those as a single linebreak. The editors, however, display one extra line resulting in two linebreaks.

As a workaround and to verify if that's the case you could replace those illegal line breaks using the following before writing the `content` to the file:

```
content = content.replace(/\r\r\n/g,"\r\n");
```

Comment: @user1283776: just out of curiosity - did this help/have you found the cause for the error?

Comment: You solved my problem, Thanks! Iam still scartching my head about why the files have \r\r\n new line characters.

Comment: Happy to hear that! Maybe this explains it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235151